# Counters for each item in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I know that some similar issues already have been posted here, but I cannot find the solution for my issue and here I am stuck with this code.
The problem is when I want to Increase or Decrease a counter, all other counters changes. Also I'm wondering were should I store the counter, should it be a unique variable or an array for each item.. ?

I'm having:

**product_items.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Item from "./product_item";

class Items extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state.unique = 0;
  }

  state = {
    brands: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: "Water0",
        price: "1.53",
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Water1",
        price: "1.47",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Water2",
        price: "1.58",
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Water3",
        price: "1.41",
        category: "Still Water",
      },
    ],
    counter: 10,
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 0 },
    ],
    filterBrands: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      filterBrands: this.state.brands,
    });
  }

  handleClick = (name) => {
    let filterBrands = [];
    if (name === "All") {
      filterBrands = this.state.brands;
    } else {
      filterBrands = this.state.brands.filter(
        (brands) => brands.category === name
      );
    }
    this.setState({ filterBrands });
  };

  addToCart = (counter) => {
    console.log("addToCart DONE");
    this.setState(({ unique }) => ({
      unique: unique + 1,
    }));
  };

  handleIncrement = (counter) => {
    // console.log(counter);
    console.log("handleIncrement DONE");
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    counters[index].value++;
    // this.setState({ counters });
    // this.setState({ unique: this.state.unique + 1 });
    // console.log(this.state.unique);
    this.setState(({ unique }) => ({
      unique: this.state.unique + 1,
    }));
  };

  handleDecrease = (counter) => {
    console.log("handleDecrease DONE");
    const counters = [...this.state.counters];
    const index = counters.indexOf(counter);
    counters[index] = { ...counter };
    counters[index].value--;
    // this.setState({ counters });
    // this.setState({ unique: this.state.unique - 1 });
    this.setState(({ unique }) => ({
      unique: this.state.unique - 1,
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="ctg-flex">
 

        <div className="items">
          {this.state.filterBrands.map((id, brands) => (
            <Item
              // key={id.key}
              key={brands}
              dataText={id.name}
              dataPrice={id.price}
              // counter_unique={this.state.counter_unique}
              unique={this.state.unique}
              // counter={this.state.counters.value}
              counters={this.state.counters}
              onClickaddToCart={this.addToCart}
              onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
              onDecrease={this.handleDecrease}
            />
          ))}
        </div>


      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Items;
```

**product_item.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Counter from "./counter";


class Item extends Component {
render() {

    return (
      <Card >
        <Card.Body>
         <Card.Text>
            this.props.unique : {this.props.unique} 
            // this.props.counters.value : {this.props.counters.value} //test isn't working
          </Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
        <Counter
          // counters={counters}
          counter={this.props.counter}
          onIncrement={this.props.onIncrement}
          onDecrease={this.props.onDecrease}
          unique={this.props.unique}
        />
        <Button         
          style={{
            display: this.props.unique === 0 ? "block" : "none",
          }}
          onClick={() => this.props.onClickaddToCart(this.props.counter)}
        >
          ADD TO CART
        </Button>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

export default Item;
```

and

**counter.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";


class Counter extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: this.props.unique === 0 ? "none" : "flex",
        }}
      >
        <Button
          onClick={() => this.props.onDecrease(this.props.counter)}
        >
          Decrease
        </Button>

        <span>
            {this.props.unique} in cart
        </span>

        <Button
          onClick={() => this.props.onIncrement(this.props.counter)}
        >
          Increase
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: You should give every counter a ID. Identifying them by value will break down if multiple have the same value

Comment: thanks @mousetail for your answer but I'm still confuse.. which parameters in which file should I change first ? I through `counter` and `unique` was my ID in this case...

Comment: You can't use properties that change for your ID

Answer (score 0):

Your counter should be an object whose key will be the id values of your products .

```
   counter  = {
     [id1] : 0 , //initially 0   
     [id2] : 0 
     ... and so on
   }
```

then each time you increase the count get the id of the product and increase the counter

```
handleIncrement = (counter) => {
    // get the id of the clicked product
    const newCounter  = { ... this.state.counter , [id] : counter[id]+1}
    this.setState({counter : newCounter})
  };
```

and get the counter value for each product object

```
   this.state.counter[productId]
```

Answer (score 0):

so final I get it, I merged product and counter in a single array to catch same single key in all array and use count properly.

**product_items.jsx**

```
 state = {
    brands: [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: "Water0",
        price: "1.53",
        value: 0,
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Water1",
        price: "1.17",
        value: 0,
      },
      ...
     ]
}


...

render() {
    return (
      <div >       
          {this.state.brands.map((item, key) => (
            <Item
              key={key}
              item={item}
              id={key}
              onClickaddToCart={this.addToCart}
              onIncrement={this.handleIncrement}
              onDecrease={this.handleDecrease}
              brands={this.state.brands}
            />
          ))}          
      </div>
    );
  }
```